# Ruby: Key lookup from a data structure based on range

Tags: ruby, search

For example, if I have the following scenario

If key is of range 1-4, then select A.
If key is of range 5-6, then select B.

I found several answers using various data structures in Java. Suggested data structures are skiplist/tree, tree-map, linkedlist etc.

Is there any ruby implementation of them? Or how can I solve this problem in Ruby?

Comment: You can use [Range#include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Range.html#method-i-include-3F)

Comment: I wan to pass into a range with a key the range it points to.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a class which can serve this purpose:

```
class RangedKeyHash < Hash
  def [](key)
    case key
    when 1..4
      super("A")
    when 5..6
      super("B")
    else
      raise KeyError, "#{key} not valid"
    end
  end
end
```

Testing:

```
hash = RangedKeyHash.new
hash["A"] = "value for A"
hash["B"] = "value for B"
hash[2]
# => "value for A"
hash[5]
# => "value for B"
hash[100]
# => KeyError
```

There's not a use-case that easily comes to mind but it is possible at least.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
class RangedHash
  def initialize(hash)
    @hash = hash.to_hash
  end

  def [](key)
    @hash.find do |k, v|
      break v if k.respond_to?(:include?) && k.include?(key) || k == v
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
hash = RangedHash.new(1..4 => 'A', 5..6 => 'B')

hash[2] => "A"    
hash[5] => "B"  
hash[7] => nil
```

Comment: I like this one. However, the runtime is still o(n). Wondering if there is a o(logn) solution.

Comment: I don't know that there is, hash lookups are based on object equality I believe so you can't just try to compare a number with to a range and expect it to work.

Comment: Here's a discussion I found (ahem! google) on this topic: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/148494